# Print line numbers of matching values

Tags: python

I have a python script that I'm using to parse a log file and print out matching errors, etc. What I'd like to do is also print the line number that the matching entry was found on.

I've seen a few similar posts such as;
[Search File And Find Exact Match And Print Line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718068/python-search-file-and-find-exact-match-and-print-line) 
But I haven't been able to apply the examples successfully.

My code is:

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

with open(filename) as f:
        data = f.read().splitlines()
        # Process counts and matches of events:
        assertmatch = [s for s in data if "Assertion" in s]
        assertcount = len(assertmatch)

if assertcount > 0:
    print " "
    print "ASSERTIONS:"
    print '\n'.join([str(myelement) for myelement in assertmatch])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can build your `assertmatch` using enumerate. The code would be something like the following:

```
assertmatch = []
for i, s in enumerate(data, 1):
    if "Assertion" in s:
        assertmatch.append('Line %05d: %s' % (i, s,))
```

There is no need to change the remaining code.

Answer (score 0):

You can read each line into a dictionary with the key being the line number then run your matching algorithm on each dictionary item. If it matches, print the key.

```
content = {}

with open(filename) as f:
    lineNum = 0
    for line in f:
        content[lineNum] = line
        lineNum = lineNum + 1

# Do search for each in content, if match, print line key.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print [(i,line) for i,line in enumerate(open(filename),1) if "Assertion" in line]
```