# How to search a variable in a file, textwrapper has no attribute to find

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am programming a dice game that only allows authenticated users to play, I have a method of appending and creating a password to a file. But I cannot search for a specific password that the user enters. My main goal for the section of the program is to create an 'if' statement that checks if the computer has found the specific password or not.

I am new to using the find statement, I have looked through many questions and examples over the past few days to no avail - I cannot get my head around how it would work with my code.

```
def Lock_Screen():
    print("Welcome")

    print("Log in(1) or Sign up(2)") 
    User_Choice = input("")

    if User_Choice == "1":
        print("Input your three-digit code:")
        UserInput = input(str(""))
        x = open("PasswordList.txt" , "r")
        x.find(Userinput)
        if x.find(UserInput):
            Start_Screen()



    elif User_Choice == "2":        
        Password = random.randint(100,999)
        f = open("PasswordList.txt" , "a+")
        x = open("PasswordList.txt" , "r")
        PasswordList = x.read()
        while Password == PasswordList:                 
            Password = random.randint(100,999)  



        print("This is your password:    " , Password)
        f = open("PasswordList.txt" , "a+")                      
        f.write(str(Password))            
        f.close()
        Lock_Screen()


    else:                                    
        print("That was not a valid answer") 
        Lock_Screen()       

Lock_Screen()
```

The .find statement is suppose to find the variable but it just returns with an error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search File And Find Exact Match And Print Line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718068/search-file-and-find-exact-match-and-print-line)

Comment: From help(open): Open a file using the file() type, returns a file object.
open() returns the file object. You need to read the contents of the file using this file object and search the contents in the data that's read. So, first do a x.read() (or x.readlines()), store the output in a variable (say data) and then do a data.find(). Note, it may not yield the accurate result as find() returns the lowest index in S where substring sub is found. So, you may want to do an exact comparison - say read line by line and match each line against the expected password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open files do not *have* a method named `find`.  You seem to be looking for

```
Userinput = input("Input your three-digit code: ")

with open(filename) as x:
    for line in x:
        if line.rstrip('\n') == Userinput:
            print("password correct")
            break
    else:
        print("password not found")
```

The `with` context manager takes care of closing the open file handle when you are done.

Comment: what is the purpose of \n

Comment: Every line in a valid text file ends with a newline character. We chop that off so that we can compare against the user's input, which does not have a newline.